# CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12 on Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, crystalreports

I have very little experience installing Crystal Reports Runtime...pretty much no experience.  My boss recently built several Windows Server 2012 r2 machines for a project we are working on.  A vendor is installing applications on the servers and have run into an issue installed CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12.msi.

When attempting to install, the following steps are take.
Double click CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12.msi
Click Next
Accept the License Agreement and click next
Click Next
The installation status bar appears for a fraction of a second and then a Windows Installer warning displays "The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation."

The vendors are local administrators on the machines and we do not have any special local policies set on the machines.  No group policies apply to these machines that don't apply to the rest of the machines on our network.  The application logs are pretty vague and list the error status as 1602 and 1625.

I also noticed that on the msi Digital Signature Details, the certificate is valid from 6/27/2013 to 6/29/2015, so I am wondering if there is a local security policy that I can't find that is blocking the install[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH1SG.png)

Answer (score -1):

Running from Command Prompt resolved this issue